# WCF Response is not mapping always returning null

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl, wcf-binding

I have the following WSDL file and created the WCF connected service using visual studio. It created the Reference.cs file (attached below after the WSDL file content). when I tired to call a service with request body it hitting the server but the response is not mapping in the WCF side, I tried the same in soap UI getting response there.

WSDL:
Refernce.cs

```
namespace ServiceReference
{
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:cdc:iisb:2011", ConfigurationName="ServiceReference.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap")]
public interface HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap
{
    
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="Address", ReplyAction="*")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference.submitMessageResponse> submitMessageAsync(ServiceReference.submitMessageRequest request);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class submitMessageRequest
{
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="submitMessage", Namespace="urn:cdc:iisb:2011", Order=0)]
    public ServiceReference.submitMessageRequestBody Body;
    
    public submitMessageRequest()
    {
    }
    
    public submitMessageRequest(ServiceReference.submitMessageRequestBody Body)
    {
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="")]
public partial class submitMessageRequestBody
{
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
    public string userid;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=1)]
    public string password;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=2)]
    public string dataownerid;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=3)]
    public string cdphprogramid;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=4)]
    public string cdphprogramenvironment;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=5)]
    public string action;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=6)]
    public string messagecontent;
    
    public submitMessageRequestBody()
    {
    }
    
    public submitMessageRequestBody(string userid, string password, string dataownerid, string cdphprogramid, string cdphprogramenvironment, string action, string messagecontent)
    {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.password = password;
        this.dataownerid = dataownerid;
        this.cdphprogramid = cdphprogramid;
        this.cdphprogramenvironment = cdphprogramenvironment;
        this.action = action;
        this.messagecontent = messagecontent;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class submitMessageResponse
{
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="submitMessageResponse", Namespace="urn:cdc:iisb:2011", Order=0)]
    public ServiceReference.submitMessageResponseBody Body;
    
    public submitMessageResponse()
    {
    }
    
    public submitMessageResponse(ServiceReference.submitMessageResponseBody Body)
    {
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="")]
public partial class submitMessageResponseBody
{
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
    public string status;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=1)]
    public string @return;
    
    public submitMessageResponseBody()
    {
    }
    
    public submitMessageResponseBody(string status, string @return)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
public interface HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapChannel : ServiceReference.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
public partial class HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ServiceReference.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap>, ServiceReference.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap
{
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);
    
    public HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient() : 
            base(HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetDefaultBinding(), HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
            base(HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }
    
    public HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }
    
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference.submitMessageResponse> submitMessageAsync(ServiceReference.submitMessageRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.submitMessageAsync(request);
    }
    
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
    }
    
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
    }
    
    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            return result;
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
    
    private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap))
        {
            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("address" +
                    "address");
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
    
    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
    {
        return HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap);
    }
    
    private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
    {
        return HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap);
    }
    
    public enum EndpointConfiguration
    {
        
        HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoap,
    }
}}
```

WCF code

```
                BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();
            b.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
                HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("endpointaddress");
            HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient = new HL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient(b, ea);
            hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(certificatedetails parameters);
            string userid = "", password = "", dataownerid = "", cdphprogramid = "", cdphprogramenvironment = "", action = "", messagecontent = @"MSH";
            submitMessageRequest submitMessageRequest = new submitMessageRequest()
            {
                Body = new submitMessageRequestBody(userid, password, dataownerid, cdphprogramid, cdphprogramenvironment, action, messagecontent)
            };
            hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.OpenAsync();
            var submitMessageResponse = await hL7SOAPEndPointSvcSoapClient.submitMessageAsync(submitMessageRequest);
```

Always getting the submitMessageResponse.body.@retun=null; submitMessageResponse.body.status=null

Comment: check if the wsdl you're using client side (and relative code) are up to date. This has happened to me when there's a need to update the service reference

Comment: Yeah the WSDL is up-to-date but the reference file generated by visual studio is the issue.  Thanks for the quick response. will post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily found the issue while posting the question itself. Am sharing my answer maybe it will helpful for someone.

The issue is in the visual studio generated Reference.cs file.
The namespace was missing in the code. I added the namespace after that it started to map correctly.

```
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace= "correctNamespace")]
public partial class submitMessageResponseBody
{
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
    public string status;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=1)]
    public string @return;
    
    public submitMessageResponseBody()
    {
    }
    
    public submitMessageResponseBody(string status, string @return)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}
```